# Logix package \Rplc symbols not working

Tags: symbols, logic

I am using LuaLatex with the [logix](https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/fonts/logix/doc/logix.pdf) package (which adds logical symbols), and all the new symbols are working except for the any of the '\Rplc' arrows. It seems as if these symbols are undefined, but they are in the package?
For example if i have simply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logix}
\begin{document}
\to 
\Rule 
\RplcAll
\end{document}
```

Then the \to symbol shows up, as does the new \Rule symbol from logix, but the \RplcAll symbol gives an undefined control sequence. How do I make use of these arrows?

Comment: works fine here in a current texlive. Is your texsystem up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using Overleaf, so it should be?

Comment: `\RplcAll` was added 2021-07-06 in version 1.09 so Overleaf should have had it in January, assuming they'd updated to TeX Live 2022 by then. Does it work now? If not, are you sure you're using the correct options for compilation on Overleaf? (I don't know if they support different versions, as well as different engines.)